# Login Screen Background

Tags: boot, login-screen, customization, plymouth

I changed the Login Screen Background picture using ubuntu-tweak. It worked!

However, after a second reboot, the picture does not appear... well, it shows up for a mili-seconds, and after that the usual LSB invades the display.

**Question**

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this thread could help:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967277  (comments #5 and #7)

The issue seems to be due to [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+bug/888186). To get around this issue you need to copy your wallpaper to /usr/share/backgrounds and then set the permissions to read only (there's 3 permissions sections, set the last two to read only and leave the first on as read/write). That should fix it. Make sure your folder containing the pictures isn't set so only your username can read the files. Set to anyone can read-only and it should work.